# Rails, CamalCase Model Name retrieving related record in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models Location and LocationType.

```
class LocationType < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location_type
end
```

In my Location model I have the foreign key: **location_type_id**

In my view I try and call:

```
 @location.location_type.name
```

but I get an error:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

How do I get the view to display the location_type related record?

Comment: What does your database look like? Can you just give us the values of @location?

Comment: @location has :name = "TEST1", :map_url = "http://....", and location_type_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

Check the `location_type_id` on your `Location` object. If there is no `LocationType` object with that id, then `@location.location_type` will return nil.

Comment: location_type = 1 and there is record in location_types with that ID

Comment: Using 'rails console' try to check and see what @location.location_type evaluates to.

Comment: @location.location_type returns the correct location_type record, but @location.location_type.name => nil